# Symmetrical supply (or almost) in Opamps and Inamps

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

My question is in relation to the symmetrical supply in opamps and inamps. I did not find this information easily on the datasheet.

I have an INA118P inamp with gain 2, and in my circuit I have *2 possibilities* of symmetrical power for it.

***First:*** +-9V coming from 2 batteries, or +-5V coming from voltage regulators (7805 and 7905).

If I were to feed with the +-9V I know there would be a slight difference between the voltages due to the quality and the life of the batteries, for example, one of my 2 batteries has more time to use than the other, so the voltage Of it and more or less 7.8V, the other is newer, and provides a voltage around 8.5V. Ie my feed would not be ideally symmetrical (+ 9V and -9V), would be **+ 7.8V and -8.5V.**

*Would this have any practical implications regarding the use of my inamp?*

***Second:*** The other possibility would be to feed with +-5V, due to the voltage regulators I know the voltage would be as accurate as possible, but *would I have a better gain with +-9V (even though it is not accurate)?* I talk about the offset voltage, CMRR, slew rate, and so on.

***Of these 2 options which would be the best?***

Just out of curiosity what I intend to amplify is a signal received by electrodes from the human body. A voltage of +-1.5V at a rate of 100KHZ is sent to the body by 2 electrodes with 1mA. Another 2 electrodes are responsible for capturing this signal, and they will be connected to the 2 inputs of the Inamp.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be affected by both PSRR and CMRR. Slow and fast variations of the rails are mostly (but not totally) ignored what with the very stiff current sources inside a silicon opamp.

Good circuits but not perfect. And unless operating conditions are exactly matched for key transistors, the high frequency PSRR and CMRR become quite low.

Problem is ---- if the operating conditions are exactly matched, then THERE IS NO SIGNAL in the opamp. [thanks to my mentor for that]

Answer (score 1):

With a gain of 2, the output will be +-3V either way. Using a larger supply voltages will let you turn the gain up with clipping the signal.

Answer (score 1):

- +PSSR @10kHz is 30~40dB
- -PSSR @10kHZ is 60dB

So higher Vcc,Vee is better for expanding CM input range but PS changes are ok.  Using Baluns with shield cable is recommended with  rightleg guard.

1mA 100kHz current source carrier will reduce impedance of electrodes but may induce CMRR errors which rectify this response carrier with low f signals if it exceeds the CM input range.

Was that for non-contact probing?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, the values of the power supplies are not important at all. They can be +5V and 0, they can be +12V and -5V, or +5V and -12V, or they can be +7.8V and -8.5V as you stated. But for inputs centered on GND, the lowest of the two power supplies is what determines the maximum excursion of the signal at the output. That is the reason that for many applications a symmetrical supply is preferred, although it is not mandatory.